# Sorting angular js ng table ignoring accents

Tags: angularjs

I try to sort a ng table (Angular js) but some string have accents and those strings are dont sorting. I try to create a filter but don't works

Someone know how to sort whit accents?

Comment: can you add some code example?

Comment: No because ,  finally i did create a new cell into my array with the name without accent and i sorting the td with this cell and i didn't use or modificate the angular js sortbale

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter in angular js by using localecompare to sort accents:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  var test=angular.module('test',[])
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [ 'Živkovič', 'Červ' , 'Šinigoj' , 'Ajinkya'];

}]).filter('localeCompareString',function(){
    return function (items) {
        items.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.localeCompare(b);
        });
        return items;
      }; 
});
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<div>
  <li ng-repeat="accent in accentArray |    localeCompareString">
         {{accent}}
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but finally i did create a new cell into my array with the name without accent and i sorting the td with this cell